# Can I paste a list of values into a Filter's search box?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer, spotfire-analyst

I am wondering if there is a way to paste a list of values (e.g. well ids) into the Spotfire Analyst's (and Web Player's) filter search box? I am new to Spotfire so not sure if that can be achieved through a custom extension or script. Basically this is what I am trying to achieve:

1. I copy some values from Excel spreadsheet
2. I open Spotfire Analyst and look for the appropriate filter on the right
3. I pates the content of my clipboard into the filter’s search box
4. Custom logic (if that’s possible?) makes sure to find the appropriate results from the filter’s list and selects them automatically
5. All charts on our page are updated and we see the results from step 4

[image]

*Please note that the solution needs to work on both the Spotfire Analyst and Web Player.*

Answer (score 1):

We work around this by using multi-line input text boxes.  Once a user pastes in a multi-line set of text values (separated by space, comma, new line, or whatever) this string is passed to a data function, which creates a table and writes that back out.  Then the two tables are related on a common key, which acts as a filter for the original table.

```
PasteAPIListTable <- data.frame(API = unlist(strsplit(PasteAPIList,PasteAPISeparator)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is there any way on how to do that without creating a table? I just don't want to be overcomplicating what I want to achieve

Comment: So you could also take the values from the multi-line input box into IronPython and filter the table from there...iterate through the list and change the filter that way.  See this link: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-get-or-set-specific-filter-using-ironpython-script-tibco-spotfire

Comment: Thanks, will take a look. I was just wondering if there is a way to achieve that without the need to add a Text area (i.e. multi line input). For example, subscribe bro the "text change" event of the Filter's search field itself

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late response but good time as any.

Spotfire's filter boxes accept boolean logic, so in your case you would want to convert the commas into the boolean operator `or`.

Example:

- `42479421240000, 42479421180000` becomes: `42479421240000 or 42479421180000`

If your list is in excel as column oriented, you can use the following excel command to create this string above: `TEXTJOIN(" or ", TRUE, starting_cell:ending_cell)`